# Blackberry hotkeys interfering with Android ListView filters

Tags: android, android-listview, blackberry-10

I am currently using a ListActivity to display a list of countries to the user. The user can type on the keyboard to filter down the list to find the country that they want.

I have done this simply by enabling the text filter of the ListActivity's ListView:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Make the loading bars available for use
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    //Enable the built in filter
    listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    //Fetch and display the countries
    if (NetworkStatus.isAvailable(this)) {
        fetchCountries();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am unable to type in a 'T' or a 'B' because these are blackberry shortcuts for Go to Top or Go to Bottom (and they do function like this within my app). Is there any way to disable this functionality or override it in some way?

I have a feeling I might be to do with what is being focused on, as there is not a problem with the other EditTexts in my app, but I am unsure of how to set the focus to the ListView filter so that the blackberry knows that the keyboard is needed.